# when forms closed txt is unsaved

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to write data in file and i don't want to lost my data after close my form.
I created a membership and i wrote textbox1,2,3 in file then when I closed the form all data lost.

```
try
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("Uye.txt", FileMode.Create);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);       
    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text);
    
    sw.Close();
    fs.Close();
    label4.Text = "Üyelik oluşturuldu";
    button2.Visible = true;
   
}
catch (Exception)
{
    label4.Text = "Üyelik oluşturulamadı";

}
```

Comment: Save on close... also what has this got to do with a database

Comment: @PaulOliver there were **many** more things to fix than just removing the database tag.

Comment: Use something like this `System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"d:\file.txt", "something");` in `Closing` event of form.

Comment: btw, not sure what data your textbox would contain, but please be aware that if the user adds a "," in those textboxes, you might end up with corrupt data when opening the form again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things

- Firstly, always wrap methods in `using` when you can.
- Secondly, if you want to save on close you will have to get notification of close, so you might want to the use the [`FormClosed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed?view=netframework-4.7.2) Event
- Lastly, you can simplify what you have to just [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) it makes sure the file handle is released, and the data is flushed to disk

**Example**

```
public void SaveData()
{
   File.WriteAllText($"{textBox1.Text},{textBox2.Text},{textBox3.Text}");
}
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   SaveData();
}
```

***Note** : I have add [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) for as its easier to read most of the time, also add exception handling to taste *

---

Just to be concise about the `using`, this would be a better pattern for what you had

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("Uye.txt", FileMode.Create))
   using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
   {
      sw.WriteLine($"{textBox1.Text},{textBox2.Text},{textBox3.Text}");
   }


// or
// note that disposing sw in the single using will dispose the file stream 
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("Uye.txt", FileMode.Create)))
{
   sw.WriteLine($"{textBox1.Text},{textBox2.Text},{textBox3.Text}");
}
```

**Update**

Useful comment from [vasily.sib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2716623/vasily-sib)

> You may also override `OnFormClosed` method of your form instead of
>   subscribing to its own events

Comment: You may also override [OnFormClosed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosed?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of your form instead of subscribing to its own events. Just don't forget to call `base` method.

Comment: @vasily.sib updated and attributed

Answer (score 0):

you should save your textbox data in event form_closing

Comment: show some code, maybe?